Conflicting definitions in pattern synonyms using a parameter more than once
Why can't I define this pattern synonym?
pattern Double a = (a,a)

error:
    • Conflicting definitions for ‘a’
      Bound at: <interactive>:1:21
                <interactive>:1:23
    • In a pattern synonym declaration


This could only work by equality-comparing the two elements of the tuple, but patterns don't just automatically spawn Eq constraints for this purpose.
You can get this functionality by using a view pattern in the definition:
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}

fromRedunTuple :: Eq a => (a,a) -> Maybe a
fromRedunTuple (x,y)
 | x==y       = Just x
 | otherwise  = Nothing

pattern Double a <- (fromRedunTuple -> Just a)
 where Double a = (a,a)


Imagine using that pattern in a function definition, and a call to it:
foo (a, a) = a

x = foo (7, 9)

Which of the two values do you expect to access with a on RHS? Double has the same ambiguity -- or rather would have if it was allowed.
Perhaps you don't really want to use Double in a matching position, but only building? Then
double x = (x, x)

is fine as an ordinary function.
